# TFS 2010 - Custom Build Activities are not deployed

Tags: visual-studio-2010, build-process

Within my teambuild we use custom build process activities, which are deployed at

```
\BuildProcessTemplates\CustomAssemblies\MyActivities.dll
```

The build controller is configured to load the assemblies from that path.

If I checkin new assemblies, then the teambuild does not load the new assemblies automatically, but uses the old ones. In fact the latest build process template seems to be used, because I get the error:

```
"TF215097: An error occurred while initializing a build for build definition <myTemplate> Cannot create unknown type <any new type>"
```

If I restart the build controller services, then the latest assemblies are considered.

How can I get teambuild to load automatically the latest assemblies, without being forced to restart the controller?

Comment: When you check-in files to the source control path monitored by your build controller, the controller should automatically restart and pickup the changes.  I don't think you should have to manually restart it.

Answer (score 5):

Finally figured this out.  Been driving me nuts for months.  Even if your binaries are technically different (i.e. binary differences), it looks like agents only get refreshed if the **file version** is different.

So more specifically, in my version of "MyActivities.dll", I had to increment the following two lines in my AssemblyInfo.cs (old version string was 1.0.0.0):

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.1")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.1")]
```

Once I did that, I did a normal build of the assembly, then checked in the new binaries.  Agents were refreshed with the new versions within minutes!  :D

Other (less awesome) options if you can't update the version for some reason:

- Check in a dummy file to the same dir.  If any files are added/removed from the CustomAssemblies dir, it forces a refresh for all files
- Change the "Version control path to custom assemblies:" value to some dummy value (doesn't matter where), apply the new value, then change back to the original directory.  Any time the path changes, that forces a refresh for all files

The "Best" solution is to just update the file/assembly version, though.

Comment: Thanks for the extra tips. I've had to use the 'change version control path' option, as just bumping the version didn't work for me

Answer (score 1):

Try to install MyActivities.dll into the GAC. I have all my custom assemblies in GAC and I didn't noticed any issues.

Comment: Wouldn't that only work until you needed to update the binaries?  The problem he's having (that I've hit too) is that the build agent is *supposed* to talk to source control to update the binaries to the latest version, but for some reason it only does that on startup (rebooting the server/service does it, but that's a bit too heavy handed).